# Firebird forcebly remove deadlock

Tags: delphi, deadlock, firebird, database-deadlocks

I'm using Delphi IBQuery and IBTransaction components to update all records in database with this query:

```
UPDATE INVOICES SET BLK = 0;
```

When users leave another client application opened it leaves deadlock on some records (opened by users).

The problem is with my application that must complete the query above.

Is it possible to implement some kind of solution to forcebly remove deadlocks? For example an SQL query?

Firebird version is 2.1.2.18118
running on Windows 7

Comment: Maybe you should reconsider **why** you need to do this. An unconditional query like that is asking for trouble in a MVCC database like Firebird when there are concurrent updates on the table. Looking at the name 'blk', it seems like you are trying to undo some sort of pessimistic locking. Maybe you should add a condition (eg `WHERE BLK <> 0`)

Comment: BLK - is a status of invoice that value is invisible to user, it shows whether the invoice was transfered to the main database or not. After the transfer I need to change this value in order to forbid users to transfer invoices again.

Comment: Still, updating only those that aren't 0 will probably reduce the likelyhood of deadlock.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! It's always a pleasure to receive valuable comments from experienced programmers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Best option would be to refactor those applications.

Natural mode for FB/IB would be to have two parallel transactions.

- **#1** would be read-only read-committed, never-closing, it would be only used for reading data.
- **#2** would be opened/committed with short bursts to actually apply changes. Any data "in editing" would not be opening transaction per se.

Long-living editing transaction are affecting database by blocking garbage collection and forcing it (and indices) to contain lot of bogus data.

I dunno if you can do this via IBX + IBQuery + some kind of custom update queries like TUpdateSQL was in bDE times. 3rd-party FB connection libs usually have some support for bi-transactional mode.

This approach however imposes a very specific pattern of how your application should be designed and makes Firebird unable to warrant data consistency - this is now your application's burden. The comments brought a nice link about it:      [Re: [firebird-support] Long read-only Transactions](http://fb-list-archive.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/firebird-support/2008/6/94903.html)

---

In modern Firebird you can forcibly drop transactions, if you have database admin/owner role. Read about Monitoring tables. Note that there were bugs in 2.5.1 so you'd probably wait for 2.5.2 release.

- http://www.upscene.com/documentation/fbtm2/index.html?dm_monitoringtables.htm
- c:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_2_5\doc\README.monitoring_tables.txt

However if you'd forcibly rollback those transaction - how would applications behave ? the user would still be editing just to suddenly discover most of his changes were lost.

PS. http://www.sql.ru/forum/actualthread.aspx?tid=910920 this code uses `mon$transactions` to map transaction to connection and then forcibly disconnects offending application. If direct `delete from mon$transactions where...` would not be available, then that would be the option left.

PPS. Since FB 2.1 long-time transactions should better be committed (and closed) each few minutes (even r/o ones). The reason is if they would happen to use BLOB calculations that may lead to uncontrollable grow of the database only reset by transactions closing. While this might trigger re=reading of all the db-aware controls, working with the transaction without intermediate caching like MIDAS ClientDataset, that is arguably still better than database inflation, that in some rare cases reported to be very fast.

Comment: The problem is the application that makes deadlock cannot be refactored or edited in any way. It's sources are closed and it's maintained by another company, which doesn't want to discuss this topic. Most of my applications are like crutches to support something that their application doesn't support.

Comment: Beside I did upvoted this answer and use it in my softwares, I find in obligation to comment what Helen B. said: "it forces you to separate reads and writes into different transactions, which breaks the "C" (consistency) part of the "ACID" rules and really pushes Firebird downhill in the league table! It takes a lot of cleverness to achieve consistency with this style of application." [source](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/firebird-support/message/94903)

Comment: Okay then, one more clarification: `read-only read-committed, never-closing transaction` can have unexpected consequences: BLOB handles leak. Because of plain C API Firebird can not know whether client application discarded BLOB handle or not, those would only be released on commit/rollback. So if you read BLOBs (like using `List(varchar column)` function in Firebird 2.1 but not 2.5+) - those would slowly exhaust FB resources. So, actually, closing such an "eternal" transction once every N minutes would be better.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to decide the problem with a bit of user interaction.

First, I'm checking whether any of the invoices are being edited by users.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MON$RECORD_STATS WHERE MON$STAT_GROUP = 2 AND MON$RECORD_UPDATES <> 0
```

Then, if there are any locks found during the above query execution I'm showing a message to user "Please close all opened invoices...", and I create a ***failed.sql*** file with the query that has to be executed in case if user just terminates my application.

On the next launch of my application, I check whether the ***failed.sql*** file exists and try to execute it again with deadlock check.

So my app became a bit more annoying to user, but it doesn't make any unattended actions that can bring frustration to users.